# Do I need an eTA if entering Canada by train from USA (UK citizen with ESTA for USA)

Tags: eta

Do I need an eTA if entering Canada by train at Niagara, Ontario from USA? I am a British citizen and already have an ESTA for the USA

Comment: Is there any information on the [eTA site](http://www.cic.gc.ca/English/visit/eta.asp) that causes you to be uncertain of the answer?

Comment: @Ambo100 I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 8):

> **If you’re travelling by land or sea, you won’t need an eTA when you
>   enter Canada.** However, you must travel with acceptable travel
>   documents and identification.

**[UK GOV: Canada Travel Advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/canada/entry-requirements)**